# How can I access an IFRAME from the codebehind file in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I am trying to set attributes for an IFRAME html control from the code-behind aspx.cs file.

I came across a [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128094503/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37635.aspx) that says you can use FindControl to find the non-asp controls using:

The aspx file contains:

```
<iframe id="contentPanel1" runat="server" />
```

and then the code-behind file contains:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlControl contentPanel1 = (HtmlControl)this.FindControl("contentPanel1");
    if (contentPanel1 != null)
        contentPanel1.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

}
```

Except that it's not finding the control, contentPanel1 is null.

---

**Update 1**

Looking at the rendered html:

```
<iframe id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_contentPanel1"></iframe>
```

i tried changing the code-behind to:

```
HtmlControl contentPanel1 = (HtmlControl)this.FindControl("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_contentPanel1");

if (contentPanel1 != null)
    contentPanel1.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.clis.com";
```

But it didn't help.

i am using a MasterPage.

---

**Update 2**

Changing the aspx file to:

```
<iframe id="contentPanel1" name="contentPanel1" runat="server" />
```

also didn't help

---

**Answer**

The answer is obvious, and unworthy of even asking the original question. If you have the aspx code:

```
<iframe id="contentPanel1" runat="server" />
```

and want to access the iframe from the code-behind file, you just access it:

```
this.contentPanel1.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: Look at the rendered HTML (view source) and find the rendered id of the iFrame. Use that in your code. We can clear it up later, but just try that.

Comment: That didn't help. Updated question to include the try.

Comment: With the masterpage you can also do this to get the iframe: Master.FindControl("contentPanel1") and set the src etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the iframe is directly on the page where the code is running, you should be able to reference it directly:

```
contentPanel1.Attribute = value;
```

If not (it's in a child control, or the MasterPage), you'll need a good idea of the hierarchy of the page...  Or use the brute-force method of writing a recursive version of FindControl().

Comment: You're right. i just blindly stumbled across it when looking for RyanFetz's recursive find.

this.contentPanel1.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

works just fine!

i just assumed it wouldn't work because it's not an asp:iframe control. i assume runat=server makes it work?

Comment: Yeah, using runat=server makes it a server-side control of some kind.

Answer (score 14):

This works for me.

**ASPX :**

```
<iframe id="ContentIframe" runat="server"></iframe>
```

I can access the iframe directly via id.

**Code Behind :**

```
ContentIframe.Attributes["src"] = "stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: And the field will be like this `protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl ContentIframe` as there is no Iframe specific WebControl

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
this.Master.FindControl("ContentId").FindControl("controlId")
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your iframe embedded?

Having this code

```
<body>

<iframe id="iFrame1" runat="server"></iframe>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>
      <iframe id="iFrame2" runat="server"></iframe>
</div>
</form>
```

I can access with `iFrame1.Attributes["src"]` just to iFrame1 and not to iFrame2.

Alternatively, you can access to any element in your form with:

```
FindControl("iFrame2") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating contentPanel1 outside the Load event; keep it global to the class.

Comment: A little bit of vocab here - Instantiating usually mean actually creating the object instance. What he's doing there is merely getting a reference to an existing object (instantiated by generated code) from a page method.

Answer (score 0):

The FindControl method looks in the child controls of the "control" the method is executed on.  Try looking through the control collection recursively.

```
    protected virtual Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, String id)
    {
        if (root.ID == id) { return root; }
        foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
        {
            Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
            if (t != null)
            {
                return t;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: He knows where it is; your solution is a friggen jackhammer where a tack hammer would do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

ContentPlaceHolder cplHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.CurrentMaster.FindControl("contentMain");

HtmlControl cpanel= (HtmlControl)cplHolder.FindControl("contentPanel1");

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="yourIframe" clientIDMode="static" runat="server"></iframe>
```

You should them be able to find your iframe using the findcontrol method.

setting `clientIDMode` to `Static` prevents you object from being renamed while rendering.

Answer (score 0):

None of your suggestions worked for me, here is my solution:

```
add src="<%=_frame1%>" //to the iframe id="frame1" html control
public string _frame1 = "http://www.google.com";
```

Answer (score -1):

aspx page

```
<iframe id="fblikes" runat="server"></iframe>
```

Code behind

this.fblikes.Attributes["src"] = "/productdetails/fblike.ashx";

Very simple....

Comment: Please leave a comment, if you down vote or up vote. I don't know why down vote or up vote. Let me explain. I want to know and recover my mistake, what I've done!