# How to get an IFrame src attribute value from ASP.Net code behind?

Tags: asp.net, iframe

Using

`string iframeSrcPage = iframeMain.Attributes["src"];`

to get iframe source, always returns the value which set in aspx page itself,
even that value is changed using javascript code,

```
iframeObject.src = pageURL;
```

So, how to get an IFrame src attribute value from ASP.Net code behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: add a `hidden` input field (with `runat="server"` attribute) and  change its value to your IFrame's `src` in the JavaScript. That way, you'll be able to read the field's value server-side.

Comment: Is there anyway to retrieve it directly using iFrame attribute itself?

Comment: Not if you change it on the client-side without perpetuating the value in a server-side control. Did you try my suggestion and it didn't work?

Comment: No, your suggestion works properly but I wonder if I could retrieve it directly using iFrame attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Just found this post, and another post with a better answer.

Here are the details:

```
this.iframeMain.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

Taken from:
[How can I access an IFRAME from the codebehind file in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168236/how-can-i-access-an-iframe-from-the-codebehind-file-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

it will work fine..

```
Iframe_id.Attributes.Add("src","YourPage.aspx?label="+123);
```