# Get HTML source code from iFrame in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I am working on iframes in ASP.NET. Below is the HTMlL code for iframe:

```
<iframe id="mainiFrame" name="mainiFrame" scrolling="auto" frameborder="2" 
            height="400px" width="500px"            
            src="" 
            runat="server"></iframe>
```

I am able to set the source of the iframe:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainiFrame.Attributes["src"] = "http://roboticsindia.com";  
    }
```

How do i get the HTML source code from the iFrame?

Regards,
Anil

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168236/how-can-i-access-an-iframe-from-the-codebehind-file-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the Html source of an iFrame is a property or not, however you could do it like so.

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
String s = wc.DownloadString(mainiFrame.Attributes["src"]);
```

Comment: Worked fine for this site, but threw a 401 error when trying to access a 'https:' page

Comment: If your https page requires a login using something like basic or challenge then it probably will cause a 401, the WebClient won't use the same session as your iFrame.

I tried it on an https page that didn't require a login and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

if page "http://roboticsindia.com" is not in your project 
you can try Webclient to get the HTML content...

Answer (score 0):

we can set the HTML I frame attributes as below.The "testframe" is the id of I frame

```
this.testframe.Attributes["src"] = "http://examples.com";
```

Comment: Bhaskarreddy Mule, have you read the question? `I am able to set the source of the iframe:` & `How do i get the HTML source code from the iFrame?`