# Can't reference iFrame in code behind file

Tags: asp.net, .net

I've got an iFrame in an aspx marked as `runat="server"`. But for some reason I can't reference it in the code behind file.

This is how it's declared in the aspx.

```
<iframe ID="iFrame" runat="server"></iframe>
```

This is where it throws an error in the code behind:

```
iFrame.Attributes["src"] = strUrl + strFile.Split('.')[0] + ".html";
```

The error is "The name 'iFrame' does not exist in the current context"

Anyone know why I can't reference it?

Comment: You might want to check some answers in this question (though the one marked as the correct answer might not help you much, the others will): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168236/how-can-i-access-an-iframe-from-the-codebehind-file-in-asp-net

Comment: Name collision?  Works fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

Where is your iframe embedded?

Having this code

```
<body>

<iframe id="iFrame1" runat="server"></iframe>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>
      <iframe id="iFrame2" runat="server"></iframe>
</div>
</form>
```

I can access with `iFrame1.Attributes["src"]` just to iFrame1 and not to iFrame2.

Alternatively, you can access to any element in your form with:

```
FindControl("iFrame2") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
```